# How Can I Get the Navigation Path of a Node in a JSON Tree While Iterating Through the Tree

Tags: javascript, json, iteration

JSON Excerpt:

```
{
    "a": {
        "b1" : {
            "c1" : {
                "d1" : "D1",
                "d2" : "D2",
                "d3" : "D3"
            },
            "c2" : {
                "d4" : "D4",
                "d5" : "D5"
            }
        },
        "b2" : {
            "c3" : {
                "d6" : D6
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to iterate the JSON Tree and obtain a list of 'd' series values with the navigation path of each 'd' node, such as

```
[{'name': 'd1', 'value': 'D1', 'path': ['a', 'b1', 'c1']},...]
```

Here, I wrote a function as follows:

```
        function GetParameters(obj) {
            for (var sProp in obj) {
                if(typeof(obj[sProp]) == "string") {
                    parameters.push({'name':sProp,'value':obj[sProp]})                                      
                } else {
                    GetParameters(obj[sProp]);                              
                }
            }               
        }
```

This function only generate the 'name' and 'value' parts of each 'd' record, but how can I get the 'path' part done in this function?

Any workarounds are welcomed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an iterative and recursive approach with supplying the actual path to the next recursion.

If an end node is found, then a new object is pushed to the result array with the visited nodes.

```js
function getPath(object) {

    function iter(o, path) {
        Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
            if (typeof o[k] === 'object') {
                return iter(o[k], path.concat(k));
            }
            result.push({ name: k, value: o[k], path: path });
        });
    }

    var result = [];
    iter(object, []);
    return result;
}

var data = { "a": { "b1": { "c1": { "d1": "D1", "d2": "D2", "d3": "D3" }, "c2": { "d4": "D4", "d5": "D5" } }, "b2": { "c3": { "d6": "D6" } } } };

console.log(getPath(data));
```

Comment: One is that, you add a new argument 'search' which I cannot provide. The other is the result is not what is wanted.

Comment: it the d series. was the question to get the path only at the end of the branch?

Comment: Actually, the innermost node is always a string, which is wrapped by a certain object. And for some reason, string nodes are not always in the same depth.

Comment: And for some reason, string nodes are not always in the same depth.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!